# Combobox Performance with many Elements in WPF

Tags: wpf, combobox

I have created a ComboBox containing some 1500 elements.
This ComboBox is horrobly slow at first time even fill the collection with stored procedure
What can I do ?

Here are Code`

```
<ComboBox  Name="cbMember" TextSearch.TextPath="MemberFullName" VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" IsEditable="True" Height="23" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5,0,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding MemberCollection}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedSearchMember,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"  KeyDown="cbMember_KeyDown"  DropDownClosed="cbMember_DropDownClosed"  SelectionChanged="cbMember_SelectionChanged">
                        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding MemberFullName}"  VerticalAlignment="Center"  />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <VirtualizingStackPanel />
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
                    </ComboBox>`
```

and fill the observable collection code are here

```
 MemberCollection = new ObservableCollection<PROC_MembersList_Result>(_context.PROC_MembersCollectionList().Where(c => c.IsHide != null && (bool)c.IsHide == true));
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a matter of knowing if it's the remote call that takes long or if it's WPF that takes a while to render all the elements (meaning the virtualization isn't working).

For the first matter, move the remote call in your constructor:

```
public MyViewModel()
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
    {
       var members = new ObservableCollection<PROC_MembersList_Result>(
           _context.PROC_MembersCollectionList()
                    .Where(c => c.IsHide != null && (bool)c.IsHide == true));

       Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => 
       {
           MemberCollection = members;
       }));
    }
}
```

What this does is it makes the remote call in a separate thread so as not to freeze your app, and then it uses the dispatcher to set `MemberCollection` on the UI thread (otherwise you get a cross thread exception).

For the second matter, google around, the issue of correct virtualization can be tricky to resolve.